# How to add links to dropdown/autocomplete submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, arraylist

I have made a form that has autocomplete field that has dropdown of different countries. No what I want to do is when someone selects the country and click on submit, it should go to different links. How can i do that in javascript?

https://codepen.io/devpatelwebdeveloper/pen/KYPjLV

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more to ( it should go to different links. )?
If I understand you correctly

Try using this:

```
  <form id="exampleForm" autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input class="go_to" type="submit">
  </form>

 <script>
 $(".go_to").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#exampleForm').attr('action', "/test").submit();
  });
 </script>
```